# Reset custom variable to default value programmatically

Tags: elisp, variables, custom

**Q:** Using Elisp, how can I reset a variable to its default value without knowing what that value is?

I tried to figure out how to do this by bringing up the [Customize interface](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html) for a variable I set to a non-default value in my init-file and pressing <kbd>C-h k</kbd> followed by a click on the "Revert..." button. That brought up the documentation for [`widget-button-click`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun%2Fwidget-button-click.html), which obviously didn't help much. (Similarly, <kbd>C-h k</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> with point on the button shows help for [`Custom-newline`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun%2FCustom-newline.html), which is also not what I am looking for.)

Comment: Related, for non-custom vars: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/10800/50

Answer (score 28, accepted):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Variable Definitions`

> Internally, `defcustom` uses the symbol property `standard-value` to record the expression for the standard value, `saved-value` to record the value saved by the user with the customization buffer, and `customized-value` to record the value set by the user with the customization buffer, but not saved. See [Symbol Properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Properties.html). These properties are lists, the `car` of which is an expression that evaluates to the value.

Hence:

```
(setq foo (eval (car (get 'foo 'standard-value))))
```

Note that this only applies to `defcustom` variables (i.e. "user options"). Emacs does not save the initial value of a `defvar` variable anywhere.

Comment: Actually, you need to evaluate the vale in the plist. Your example should be changed to: `(setq foo (eval (car (get 'foo 'standard-value))))` The default value form generated by `defcustom` is a form with a funcall and a closure (this is possibly happening only when lexical binding is enabled)

Comment: You probably want to use `setq-default` rather than `setq` in this case.

Answer (score 17):

Another, probably cleaner, way to reset the value of a variable:

> `custom-reevaluate-setting` is a compiled Lisp function in `custom.el`.
>
> `(custom-reevaluate-setting SYMBOL)`
>
> Reset the value of `SYMBOL` by re-evaluating its saved or standard value.
>   Use the `:set` function to do so.  This is useful for customizable options
>   that are defined before their standard value can really be computed.
>   E.g. dumped variables whose default depends on run-time information.

So for example:

```
(custom-reevaluate-setting 'emms-player-next-function)
```

will replace the previous value with that symbol's `standard-value`.

**EDIT**

Read @phils comment below for a very important detail regarding this function.

Comment: Note "**saved** or standard value". In that order of precedence. If the user has customized and saved a value for the variable, this function resets it to its `saved-value`, not its `standard-value`.

Answer (score 2):

Building up from the accepted answer I've made a function for it.

```lisp
(defun custom/reset-var (symbl)
  "Reset SYMBL to its standard value."
  (set symbl (eval (car (get symbl 'standard-value)))))

(custom/reset-var 'somevar)
```

Comment: The outer `eval` is unnecessary; just pass the function's argument to `set` instead of `setq`.

Comment: Thanks @Basil I've adjusted