# Set (non-custom) variable to its initial value

Tags: elisp, variables

Is there a (quick) way of resetting a variable to its default value (as defined in some .el file) after it has been modified? e.g. via commands in the .emacs file, without having to restart emacs.

Example:
Set `ispell-tex-skip-alists` to the value as defined in `ispell.el' after modification.

Comment: Related: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3022/50.  (I've edited your title to not be a duplicate of it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
(defun endless/reset-var-at-point ()
  "Revaluate the definition of variable at point."
  (interactive)
  (save-window-excursion
    (save-excursion
      (let ((buf (current-buffer)))
        (find-variable-at-point)
        (when (looking-at-p "(def\\(var\\|custom\\|const\\) ")
          (eval-defun nil))
        (unless (equal buf (current-buffer))
          (bury-buffer (current-buffer)))))))
```

As others have stated, the initial value of a `defvar` is not stored
anywhere. However, the location of its definition does get stored by
Emacs, so you can visit it and reevaluate it.

Note that this will only work if the location of the variable is
known, and if it is defined in a conventional way (not as part of a
wierd macro or something).
It will also leave a buffer hanging around.

So it is very much **not designed for used in lisp code**. For
interactive use, it should do just fine.

Comment: ...in which I learn that `C-M-x` (`eval-defun`) in a variable (or face) definition actually resets its value (unlike other forms of re-evaluation, which do not).

Answer (score 4):

No.  Non-custom variables need not even *have* a default value.

Except if you mean a global value as opposed to a **buffer-local** value. In the case of a variable that has buffer-local values, yes, you can use function **`default-value`** to obtain its default value, and you can then use `setq` to set any buffer-local value to that default value.  (You can also use `set-default-value` to change the default value.)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible if the variable was declared as a `defcustom`:

```cl
(eval (car (get 'ediff-split-window-function 'standard-value)))
;; => split-window-vertically
```

But `ispell-tex-skip-alists` was declared as `defvar`, so this isn't possible.

Comment: Technically, you can visit the variable definition and reevaluate it entirely with elisp code.

Comment: True, but there's no introspection-style option.

Comment: The question explicitly asks about a **non-custom** variable.

Comment: The question was edited two hours **after** I provided an answer.