# AUCTeX isn't loading local per-package style files, is ignoring `TeX-auto-local`

Tags: auctex

My AUCTeX setup isn't loading any local per-package auto-generated style files.  Suppose I have a simple package `doc-preamble.sty`

```latex
% doc-preamble.sty
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newcommand*{\mycmd}[1]{Hello, #1!}
```

and I use that in `doc-main.tex` (in the same directory):

```latex
% doc-main.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{doc-preamble}

\usepackage{url}
\newcommand*{\myothercmd}[1]{Goodbye, #1!}

\begin{document}

This is a test.

\end{document}
```

Then, when working in `doc-main.tex`, the configuration for `doc-preamble.sty` isn't loaded.  In this case, that means that `\cref` (from `cleveref`) and `\mycmd` don't show up as autocomplete results for `TeX-insert-macro` (<kbd>C-c C-m</kbd>), the `\cref` reference style isn't available to RefTeX, etc.

The configuration for `doc-main.tex`, on the other hand, *is* available, so configuration in general works: commands like `\url`, as well as `\myothercmd`, are both available from `TeX-insert-macro` (<kbd>C-c C-m</kbd>), and `\url` is correctly formatted as a verbatim command.

The value of `TeX-active-styles` in `doc-main.tex` is, strangely,

```
("url" "doc-preamble" "art10" "article" "latex2e" "doc-main" "LATEX")
```

So AUCTeX knows that `doc-preamble` is being used, but not what to do when using it.

Relatedly, the AUCTeX `.el` files *are* being generated, so that's not the issue. They even look right:

```lisp
;; doc-preamble.el
(TeX-add-style-hook
 "doc-preamble"
 (lambda ()
   (TeX-run-style-hooks
    "cleveref")
   (TeX-add-symbols
    '("mycmd" 1)))
 :latex)
```

```lisp
;; doc-main.el
(TeX-add-style-hook
 "doc-main"
 (lambda ()
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-braces-local "url")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-braces-local "path")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-delims-local "url")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-delims-local "path")
   (TeX-run-style-hooks
    "latex2e"
    "article"
    "art10"
    "doc-preamble"
    "url")
   (TeX-add-symbols
    '("myothercmd" 1)))
 :latex)
```

The `doc-preamble.el` file simply isn't being loaded as far as I can tell.

---

Thanks to [giordano](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/620/giordano), I was able to find a possible reason for this behavior.  (This reason is still a symptom of whatever the underlying problem is.)

My AUCTeX configuration includes the line `(setq TeX-auto-local ".auctex-auto")`.  And while this variable retains its value, when I query `TeX-style-path` with <kbd>C-h C-v</kbd>, I get (reformatted)

```
TeX-style-path is a variable defined in `tex.el'.
Its value is
("/usr/local/var/auctex" "/Users/antal/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.4/style"
 "/Users/antal/.emacs.d/auctex/auto" "/Users/antal/.emacs.d/auctex/style"
 "auto" "style")

Original value was 
("/usr/local/var/auctex" "/Users/antal/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.4/style"
 "/Users/antal/.emacs.d/auctex/auto" "/Users/antal/.emacs.d/auctex/style"
 ".auctex-auto" "style")
```

Note that, somehow, my setting for `TeX-auto-local` (which correctly has the value `".auctex-auto"`) is being overwritten in `TeX-style-path`: the new value uses `"auto"` where the original used `".auctex-auto"`!

Thus, `TeX-auto-local` is being overridden, but *not* changed!  This pushes the question back to "why is this happening"?

---

I'm using AUCTeX 11.89.4.  I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, if I've got a bug in my configuration, or what, so I'm not sure which parts of my configuration are important, but here are some potentially relevant pieces of my configuration:

```lisp
(require 'tex)
(require 'latex)
(require 'reftex)

(setq TeX-auto-save  t
      TeX-parse-self t)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'reftex-mode)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX '(nil t t t t))

(setq TeX-auto-local ".auctex-auto")

(TeX-global-PDF-mode t)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'auto-fill-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'flyspell-mode)
```

There's also some custom advice that I don't think is relevant, but I've included the `advice-add` calls below in case one of those functions is dangerous to advise (the definitions of the advice functions are available if necessary):

```lisp
(advice-add #'LaTeX-indent-calculate-last
            :around #'LaTeX-indent-calculate-last--outdent-label)
(advice-add #'TeX-command-sequence-sentinel
            :after #'TeX-sentinel-manage-error-buffer)
(advice-add #'reftex-reference
            :around #'reftex-reference-negatable-prompt
            '((depth . -50)))
(advice-add #'reftex-format-special
            :filter-return #'reftex-format-special-handle-cleveref)
(advice-add #'reftex-ref-style-list
            :filter-return #'reftex-ref-style-list-maybe-preferentially)
(advice-add #'reftex-reference
            :around #'reftex-reference-no-promt-preferentially)
```

Comment: [Comments that led to the diagnosis of the problem have been moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/40692/discussion-on-question-by-antal-spector-zabusky-auctex-isnt-loading-local-per-p).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I did

```lisp
(require 'tex)
```

before

```lisp
(setq TeX-auto-local ".auctex-auto")
```

In AUCTeX, the definition of `TeX-style-path` is via a `defcustom` form, which sets `TeX-style-path` to the result of evaluating an expression that builds up a list by referring to the values of `TeX-auto-local` and similar variables.  `(require 'tex)` *before* setting `TeX-auto-local`, the value of `TeX-style-path` got set to a value that referenced the *old* value of `TeX-auto-local`, and was never reinitialized.

If I remove the `(require 'tex)`, or simply move `(setq TeX-auto-local ".auctex-auto")` before it (there are later parts of my config that require it to be loaded), then everything works fine.

Another option would be to [re-initialize `TeX-style-path`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3024/5295), about which see the next section.

---

One piece of the mysteriousness, though, is that `describe-variable` (<kbd>C-h v</kbd>) for `TeX-style-path` claimed (reformatted):

```lisp
TeX-style-path is a variable defined in `tex.el'.
Its value is
("/usr/local/var/auctex" "/Users/antal/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.4/style"
 "/Users/antal/.emacs.d/auctex/auto" "/Users/antal/.emacs.d/auctex/style"
 "auto" "style")

Original value was 
("/usr/local/var/auctex" "/Users/antal/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.4/style"
 "/Users/antal/.emacs.d/auctex/auto" "/Users/antal/.emacs.d/auctex/style"
 ".auctex-auto" "style")
```

Why was the "original value" different if nothing had ever changed `TeX-style-path`?  The answer is that `defcustom` stores, not the initial value of a variable, but the initial *expression* that created it, and re-`eval`s it to see if the "original value" was different.  Since one of the variables that `TeX-style-path`'s definition referenced was the now-changed `TeX-auto-local`, the "original value" was *inaccurate* upon recomputation.

This is also why it's possible to [reset the value of `TeX-style-path` to its "default" value](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3024/5295), as mentioned above.

---

For reference, the `defcustom` form that sets `TeX-style-path` to its default value in AUCTeX version 11.89.4:

```lisp
(defcustom TeX-style-path
  (let ((path))
    ;; Put directories in an order where the more local files can
    ;; override the more global ones.
    (mapc (lambda (file)
            (when (and file (not (member file path)))
              (setq path (cons file path))))
          (append (list TeX-auto-global TeX-style-global)
                  TeX-auto-private TeX-style-private
                  (list TeX-auto-local TeX-style-local)))
    (nreverse path))
  "List of directories to search for AUCTeX style files.
Per default the list is built from the values of the variables
`TeX-auto-global', `TeX-style-global', `TeX-auto-private',
`TeX-style-private', `TeX-auto-local', and `TeX-style-local'."
  :group 'TeX-file
  :type '(repeat (file :format "%v")))
```

As we can see, it references `TeX-auto-local`, and this is the *only* place that `TeX-style-path` is set.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of bending `TeX-auto-local` and `TeX-style-path` to your will, you might want give `TeX-auto-generate` a try instead? Also see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410393/how-to-properly-set-up-auctex-to-parse-macros-from-my-own-sty-files