# Installing AUCTeX, GNU Emacs 24.5.1

Tags: package, auctex

I'm very new to Emacs. I've installed AUCTeX version 11.89.4 using package manager (`list-packages`, select `auctex`, install it). It works, at least it shows compiled pdf result from test .tex file in local buffer after several `C-c C-c` strokes. Now I want to do some customization -- for example, showing result in external evince program. However, the more tutorials and docs I read, the more it seems to me that my AUCTeX installation is somehow broken:

- I know that `C-h v AUCTeX-version` should give me AUCTeX version. However, I don't have such variable -- describe variable gives no match. I have learned that the version is 11.89.4 from the package manager.
- I don't have variable `TeX-view-program-list`, which, as [I've read](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106889/change-view-command-in-emacs-and-auctex-pdf-mode), is used for setting view program. In fact, I have only three variables starting with `Tex`, and all of them I've declared in `initl.el` myself: `TeX-PDF-mode`, `TeX-auto-save`, `TeX-pase-self`.
- I don't have menu item `LaTeX` which is [mentioned here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161797/how-to-configure-emacs-and-auctex-to-perform-forward-and-inverse-search). I have only menu item `TeX`, and there is no "Customize AUCTeX" submenu:
  [image]
- There is no key `C-c ~` which is supposed to [turn on math mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Mathematics.html). There is no variable `LaTeX-math-abbrev-prefix` and no function `LaTeX-math-mode`, although I've added line `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)` to my `init.el` and it had been read without any problems.
- some other things, but I think this should be enough to show the problem.

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04, GNU Emacs 24.5.1. This is version is still absent from Ubuntu repos, so I have built it from sources and installed via checkinstall.

Additional info:
Ubuntu package auctex is not installed -- I just followed [manual instructions](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Installation) and it doesn't says anything about system-wide packages. I have no variable `TeX-lisp-directory`; If I start Emacs without executing init.el (-q), and then run `M-x package-initialize`, I get the following error: `(file-error "Cannot open load file" "no such file or directory" "tex-site")`. I don't know what it means right now, but it seems that google has something on this -- I will look into.

There is another point which, as I think, should be made clear. As I have read in [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA) since Emacs 24 package initialization happens after loading init.el. However, I needed `package-installed-p` function, so I forced loading packages in the beginning of init.el by inserting the following code (taken from [wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA)):

```
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(package-initialize)
```

**Update**

I didn't noticed earlier, but in fact I get error `"no such file or directory" "tex-site"` after running `package-initialize` when calling in from `init.el` too. It seems to me that the root of my problem is that I forgot to add the line `(require 'auctex)`. After adding it, auctex finally works, I have `TeX-lisp-directory` and other vars, however, now I see the following warning in Messages:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/ars/.emacs.d/init.el':

error: Required feature `auctex' was not provided
```

What's wrong with this way of loading packages? Should I require them explicitly or not?

Comment: You're running Emacs's built-in TeX mode, not AUCTeX. Is Ubuntu's `auctex` package installed? Are you running Emacs from an Ubuntu package or installed manually? What is the value of the variable `TeX-lisp-directory`? If you run `emacs -q` then `M-x package-initialize`, what is the value of the variable `TeX-lisp-directory`?

Comment: from memory: it should be `require 'latex` or `require 'tex` instead of `auctex`.

Comment: @mutbuerger thanks, `'latex` worked. If I would do it myself, where should I look for this name?

Comment: AuCTeX doesn't provide a feature called `auctex`: `(member 'auctex features)` is nil. But taking a look at the auctex directory, you'll discover a latex.el ending with `(provide 'latex)`, therefore providing the feature `latex`. latex.el requires tex.el which in turn requires tex-site.el etc. So the feature `latex` is the right "entry point". Thankfully most Elisp libraries consist of a single file.

Comment: @mutbuerger I don't know where you found the suggestion to use `(require 'anything)` to load AUCTeX: there is not a single line in [AUCTeX manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html) suggesting so.  This is not only wrong and useless, but also [harmful](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/22657/620).  I'd like to know who is suggesting this configuration on the Internet

Comment: @giordano: You are right, my comments are based on the warning ars received. Should have contacted the manual first - the relevant section in the manual: [Loading the package](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Loading-the-package).

Answer (score -2):

If packages are initialized in `init.el` by hand, it is necessary to load every used package explicitly. For auctex, loading the package is [covered in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Loading-the-package). One should also always check `*Messages*` buffer before posting questions here...

Comment: -1.  This is plainly wrong.  You don't need at all to `require` any package of AUCTeX to make it work.  This is wrong, useless and harmful.

Comment: I see, fixed now.