# Modify value of a variable by applying a function to it?

Tags: variables, setq

Suppose one of the customizable variables in a package is `var`, and its default value is a list, `list`. I understand I can change the value of `var` to `mylist` using

```lisp
(setq var mylist)
```

in my `init.el`.

Suppose though that I have a function `fun` and I want the value of `var` to be the result of applying `fun` to `list`. Can I simply do this?

```lisp
(setq var (fun var))
```

I've done it and it seems to work as intended, but I want to make sure this is a good idea.

---

**EDIT**: My question was not very clear, so let me clarify the sort of thing I was worried about (this may be redundant in light of my comment to [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/60720/9562) by [Drew](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/105/drew). Suppose I add

```lisp
(setq var (fun var))
```

to my `init.el`. How do I ensure that the default value of `var` has already been set when that line gets evaluated? Should I put this inside a  `with-eval-after-load`? And how do I ensure that `M-x load-file ~/.emacs.d/init.el` won't result in `var` being set to the value of `(fun (fun var))`? Should I instead add the above line to something like `emacs-startup-hook` or `after-init-hook`?

I'm currently using a line in my `init.el` like the above for setting a variable to a value as a function of its default value. I'm relying on `use-package`, and in order to ensure that the default value of the variable had been set I had to put that line in the `:config` section of the relevant package, rather than in the `:custom` section (without `setq`). Also, the function I am currently using has the nice feature that `(fun (fun var))` yields the same output as `(fun var)`. So I have managed to get around both of my concerns.

Still, this seemed like an opportunity to try to understand how to do what I'm trying to do even if I'm not using `use-package` and if I have a function that's not idempotent.

Comment: You might find the [Programming in Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/lispintro/) manual a useful introduction to Lisp in general and Emacs Lisp in particular.

Comment: `with-eval-after-load` is the right approach for ensuring that `var` has been defined before you try to use it.  Ensuring that you're only ever manipulating its *default* value is harder.  If it's a `defcustom` then [you do have access to its standard value](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3024/454), but this is not the case for `defvar`, so you would need to capture and store that value yourself before you changed it (notwithstanding that something else might already have gotten in ahead of you).

Comment: @phils That's exactly what I needed! Thanks very much. So, I could just do `(setq var (fun (eval (car (get 'var 'standard-value)))))` to accomplish what I want, as long as `var` is  introduced with a `defcustom`. I will accept this if you want to put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  `setq` sets a variable to whatever value is returned by the second argument.

`(setq VAR VALUE)` sets variable `VAR` to whatever `VALUE` is, and the second argument, `VALUE` is always evaluated.

(The first argument, `VAR`, is never evaluated. For a function that evaluates both args, see `set`.)

Comment: Thanks (again!) for your helpful answer. One thing I was worried about was the fact that `var` may not yet have been assigned a value by the package. Another was that I didn't know whether e.g. reloading my `init.el` file would result in `var` being changed in a non-desirable way, since it might result in `var` having its value now be the result of applying `fun` to the result of applying `fun` to the default value of `var`. Does that make sense? Should I not worry about any of this?

Comment: `C-h f defvar`. Use `defvar` to set a global variable once. Subsequent evaluation of `defvar`s for that variable have no effect. `setq` always updates an existing variable or initializes one that's never had a value.